# Is it "policy(ies)" or policy(s)" for an optional, parenthetical plural suffix?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, silent-letters, parenthetical-plural

When writing a noun that shows a parenthetical plural suffix option, which is acceptable, "policy(ies)" or policy(s)"?

Answer (score 2):

Since the difference between the words is not a simple addition of characters, using parenthesis to show the optional form is not clear.

Instead, it would be clearer to write:

> policy (or policies).